# Can I use TfidfVectorizer in scikit-learn for non-English language? Also how do I read a non-English text in Python?

Tags: python, utf-8, scikit-learn, tf-idf, text-processing

I have to read a text document which contains both English and non-English (Malayalam specifically) languages in Python. The following I see:

```
>>>text_english = 'Today is a good day'
>>>text_non_english = 'ആരാണു സന്തോഷമാഗ്രഹിക്കാത്തത'
```

Now, if I write a code to extract the first letter using

```
>>>print(text_english[0])
'T'
```

and when I run

```
>>>print(text_non_english[0])
�
```

To get the first letter, I have to write the following

```
>>>print(text_non_english[0:3])
ആ
```

Why this happens?
My aim to extract the words in the text so that I can input it to the tfidf transformer. When I create the tfidf vocabulary from the Malayalam language, there are words which are two letters which is not correct. Actually they are part of the full words. What should i do so that the tfidf transformer takes the full Malayalam word for the transformation instead of taking two letters.

I used the following code for this

```
>>>useful_text_1[1:3] # contains both English and Malayalam text

>>>vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(sublinear_tf=True,max_df=0.5,stop_words='english')

# Learn vocabulary and idf, return term-document matrix
>>>vect_2 = vectorizer.fit_transform(useful_text_1[1:3])
>>>vectorizer.vocabulary_
```

Some of the words in the vocabulary are as below:

```
ഷമ
സന
സഹ
ർക
ർത
```

The vocabulary is not correct. It is not considering the whole word. How to rectify this?

Comment: You're using *Python2* . Perhaps you'd want to switch to Python 3?

Comment: On Python 3, `text_non_english[0] == 'ആ'`

Comment: @AnttiHaapala ok. Thanks. That is helpful. There is another problem that the vocabulary generated by the tfidf transformer is not correct as it was not considering the whole word. How to rectify that?

Comment: you're psasing in `useful_text_1[1:3]` (2 bytes), what'd you expect?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala No actually. useful_text[1:3] is a set of two sentences. useful_text[1:3] = [ 'ആരാണു സന്തോഷമാഗ്രഹിക്കാത്തത്‌,പക്ഷെ,ഇനിയുംഭരണം വന്നാൽ വലിയ വില കൊടുക്കെണ്ടി വരുംചിലയിടത്ത് പെണ്ണുപിടി..ചിലയിടത്ത് അഴിമതി...എന്തിനു നാം ഇത് സഹിക്കണം.ഭരണം നിങ്ങൾക്ക്‌ ദോഷകരമാണു, അതു പോലെ നിങ്ങളുടെ പ്രിയപ്പെട്ടവർക്കും. ഭരണം വരരുത്‌,വരാനനുവദിക്കരുത്',  'Manushyn aaya oru chief Minister, athu njangal idhehathil kaanunnoo'].

Answer (score 2):

You have to encode text in utf-8. But Malayalam language's letter contains 3 symbols, so you need to use unicode function:

```
In[36]: tn = 'ആരാണു സന്തോഷമാഗ്രഹിക്കാത്തത'
In[37]: tne=unicode(tn, encoding='utf-8')
In[38]: print(tne[0])
ആ
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a dummy tokenizer actually worked for me

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=lambda x: x.split(), min_df=1)

>>> tn = 'ആരാണു സന്തോഷമാഗ്രഹിക്കാത്തത'
>>> vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=lambda x: x.split(),min_df=1)
>>> vect_2 = vectorizer.fit_transform(tn.split())
>>> for x in vectorizer.vocabulary_:
...     print x
... 
സന്തോഷമാഗ്രഹിക്കാത്തത
ആരാണു
>>>
```

Comment: can you explain this

Comment: if i encode the text first `tne = [x.encode['utf-8'] for x in tn]` and pass `tne` to `fit_transform` why does it not return unicode tokens?

Answer (score 0):

Alternative is to try [Text2Text](https://github.com/artitw/text2text) to get the TFIDF vectors. It supports 100s of languages, including Malayalam.

```
import text2text as t2t

t2t.Handler([
  'Today is a good day',
  'ആരാണു സന്തോഷമാഗ്രഹിക്കാത്തത'
]).tfidf()
```