# passing non-English text in TfidfVectorizer of scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, python-unicode, tfidfvectorizer

I used the solution given  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36498617/can-i-use-tfidfvectorizer-in-scikit-learn-for-non-english-language-also-how-do) but I want to know why encoding the text in `utf-8` doesn't return tokenized words. Here is a sample code

```
tn = ['গাড়ি রাস্তায় চালানো হয়', 'ট্রাক হাইওয়েতে চালানো হয়']
tne = [x.encode('utf-8') for x in tn]
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer() 
response = vectorizer.fit_transform(tne)
terms = vectorizer.get_feature_names() 
print(response)
print(terms)
```

```
(0, 1)  1.0
(1, 0)  0.8148024746671689
(1, 1)  0.5797386715376657
['ইওয়', 'হয়']
```

The output i want is :

```
  (0, 5)    0.40993714596036396
  (0, 1)    0.40993714596036396
  (0, 3)    0.5761523551647353
  (0, 0)    0.5761523551647353
  (1, 4)    0.5761523551647353
  (1, 2)    0.5761523551647353
  (1, 5)    0.40993714596036396
  (1, 1)    0.40993714596036396
['গাড়ি', 'চালানো', 'ট্রাক', 'রাস্তায়', 'হাইওয়েতে', 'হয়']
```

Comment: the "encode" solution you gave above isnt about tokenizing. you have to split the sentences to words nevertheless. To to add `.split()` after the encoding like `x.encode('utf-8').split()`. it might work for this simple example

Comment: `TfidfVectorizer` expects strings @luigigi

Comment: @luigigi using `.split()` gives an `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'` error

Comment: okay, then use `vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=lambda x: x.split())` instead

Comment: its even in the solution that was posted in the question. and it gives exactly the expected output. if you still wonder why `encode()` doesn't tokenize the sentences: `.encode()` only changes the encoding of that string. It has nothing to do with tokenizing. you can check the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) for more information

Comment: why is that for non-english strings, a separate tokenizer has to be written, but for english text, it is not needed? i mean, if there's a built-in tokenizer why does it correctly tokenize english text only? @luigigi